# technical editor to Copy editor

Tags: grammar

I wish to jump my career from technical editor to copy editor. I am learning grammar from online sites. I have a trouble how to begin, what are the step by step process. What should I do to become well-informed copy editor.

Comment: When I asked a Tibetan Lama, "What is the best way to learn the Tibetan language?" he replied, "Be reborn in Tibet." There are aspects of copy editing that require a good "ear" for the English language. Few non-native English speakers have this ability. Immerse yourself as much as possible in discussions with native speakers in order to improve your "ear" for what is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for career or learning advice, and not about English grammar or usage,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a used copy of the **Gregg Reference Manual**, spiral bound (so it lies flat on your desk when it is open). It is intended for business but is used by many copy editors, because it provides concise answers and examples without resorting to pedantry.
http://tinyurl.com/jk7ghou

Comment: thanks brother.. Can you help me with some good online website for copy-editing test.

Comment: Sorry, my friend, I don't know of any. Perhaps someone else here can help.